# How to control the range of values in horizontal Stacked Bar Plot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

Following is the code which gives a stacked bar chart with Timeline values from 0-300. But I want it to be from 1-24.

R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
dataFrame <- data.frame(sr=c(1:72),
                      hours=c(1:24),
                      mode=factor(c(""),levels = c("SecureMessaging","WebLogs","IVR")),
                      status=factor(c("Inactive"),levels = c("Active","Inactive")))
dataFrame$mode[1:24] <- "SecureMessaging"
dataFrame$mode[25:48] <- "WebLogs"
dataFrame$mode[49:72] <- "IVR"
dataFrame$status[2] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[7] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[24] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[2+24] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[12+24] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[15+24] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[3+48] <- "Active"
dataFrame$status[5+48] <- "Active"
dataFrame <- na.omit(dataFrame)
plot <- ggplot(data=dataFrame, aes(x=mode, y=hours, fill=status)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
plot <- plot+coord_flip()
plot <- plot+ggtitle("Data Analytics")
plot <- plot+xlab("Mode")
plot <- plot+ylab("Time Line")
print(plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically not a direct answer as I'm suggesting an alternate implementation using `geom_tile`:

```
gg <- ggplot(data=dataFrame, aes(y=mode, x=factor(hours)))
gg <- gg + geom_tile(aes(fill=status))
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + labs(x="Mode", y="Time Line", title="Data Analytics")
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I wanted to differentiate between the IVR, SecureMessage and WebLogs. Can you please suggest me for the same. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean use a different color for each one?

Comment: Not necessarily different colors, any thing that differentiate the values of the above graph would be helpful.

Comment: I want 1 seperator(horizontal line) in between IVR, secureMessaging and WebLogs.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to cut the result at 24 (in the range 0,300) then add before print(plot) the following line. The result is however not perfect yet, because the "inactive" bars stop before 24.

```
plot <- plot+ylim(0,24)
```

However, I am not sure if you wanted this. Probably you are not happy with the scaling from 0-300 that r applies and want to have it 0-24. In that case, try the following. "1" should replace "hours" in your plot function as indicated here:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=dataFrame, aes(x=mode, 1, fill=status)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: figure for second option]

Answer (score 0):

Bar chart with proper x-axis:

```
ggplot(dataFrame, aes(x=hours,y=status, fill=status))+ geom_bar(stat='identity')+ facet_grid(mode~.)
```

[image]